# Wildcard Array in If Statement in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, wildcard

What I am trying to do with this code is to :

1. Go through all the files in that specified folder and all the subfolders in that folder. (The files in that folder are usually separated in 5 parts by underscore. For example, "XX1_XX2_XX3_XX4_XX5"
2. If any of the 3 character indicators in my myarray matches XX2 from the filename, then list XX4 on Cell(22,3) and XX5 on Cell(22,4) and keep repeating ......Cell(23,3),Cell(23,4),Cell(24,3,),Cell(24,4).....etc. I want only exact matches.. not sure how to do that.
3. There are some files in the folder that has only 3 underscores... so "XX1_XX2_XX3_XX4". For these files, if myarray matches XX2, then list XX4 on Cells(i,3) and show "NO INDICATOR" for Cells(i,4)

Please let me know if I am unclear on any parts of the above description. 
This is what I have so far:

```
Sub tracker()

Const FPATH As String = "\\KEVINXX\FILESXX\FILES\"

Dim f As String, i, j As Long, arr, sht As Worksheet
Dim pvt As PivotTable, pvtCache As PivotCache
Dim myarray As Variant
myarray = Array("ABC", "XYZ", "YYY", "XXX", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "EEE", "FFF", "JJJ")
Set sht = ActiveSheet


f = Dir("\\KEVINXX\FILESXX\FILES\")
i = 22
Do While f <> ""
    'split filename on underscore
    arr = Split(f, "_", 5)
    If UBound(arr) = 4 And "*" & myarray(j) & "*" Like arr(1) Then
        sht.Cells(i, 3).Value = arr(3)
        sht.Cells(i, 4).Value = arr(4)
        f = Dir() ' next file
        i = i + 1
    Else
        sht.Cells(i, 3).Value = arr(3)
        sht.Cells(i, 4).Value = "No Indicator"
        f = Dir()
        i = i + 1
    End If

Loop
```

Comment: put the `sht.Cells(i, 3).Value = arr(3)` and `f = Dir()` and `i = i + 1` after the `end if` .... remove them from inside the `if` statement .... your `if` statement only affects the value of `sht.Cells(i, 4)`

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
Sub tracker()

    Const FPATH As String = "\\KEVINXX\FILESXX\FILES\"

    Dim f As String, i, j As Long, arr, sht As Worksheet
    Dim pvt As PivotTable, pvtCache As PivotCache
    Dim myarray As Variant
    myarray = Array("ABC", "XYZ", "YYY", "XXX", "BBB", _
                    "CCC", "DDD", "EEE", "FFF", "JJJ")
    Set sht = ActiveSheet

    f = Dir("\\KEVINXX\FILESXX\FILES\")
    i = 22
    Do While f <> ""

        'split filename on underscore
        arr = Split(f, "_", 5)

        If UBound(arr) >= 3 Then
            If Not IsError(Application.Match(arr(1), myarray, 0)) Then
                sht.Cells(i, 3).Value = arr(3)
                If UBound(arr) >= 4 Then
                    sht.Cells(i, 4).Value = arr(4)
                Else
                    sht.Cells(i, 4).Value = "No indicator"
                End If
                i = i + 1
            End If 'got match
        End If
        f = Dir() 'next file
    Loop
End Sub
```